# Change Timeframe of an RSI on a different timeframe

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

Hi guys can anyone help me set up a different time frame for the RSI strategy. For example I would like to view a 4hr timeframe rsi on a 1hr chart. Just wondering is that is possible and if you could help me set it up. Code is below and it would be helpful if you could tell me what i would have to add to make it work. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="Relative Strength Index", shorttitle="RSI-SMA(f)", overlay=false, initial_capital=100, default_qty_type=strategy.cash, default_qty_value=50, currency=currency.USD, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.07)

// Choose MA Type
ma(source, length, type) =>
    switch type
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "Bollinger Bands" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(source, length)
        "SMMA (RMA)" => ta.rma(source, length)
        "WMA" => ta.wma(source, length)
        "VWMA" => ta.vwma(source, length)

// RSI and MA inputs
rsiLengthInput = input.int(14, minval=1, title="RSI Length", group="RSI Settings")
rsiSourceInput = input.source(close, "Source", group="RSI Settings")
maTypeInput = input.string("SMA", title="MA Type", options=["SMA", "Bollinger Bands", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"], group="MA Settings")
maLengthInput = input.int(14, title="MA Length", group="MA Settings")

up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
rsiMA = ma(rsi, maLengthInput, maTypeInput)

// Plotting RSI and SMA
plot(rsi, "RSI", color=color.blue)
plot(rsiMA, "RSI-based MA", color=color.yellow)


// Conditions and Entries
longCondition= ta.crossover(rsi,rsiMA)
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long)
shortCondition= ta.crossunder(rsi,rsiMA)
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry('short', strategy.short)

// Exit Position
strategy.close('Long', when= shortCondition, comment= 'Exit Long')
strategy.close('short', when= longCondition, comment= 'Exit Short')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I made a daily moving average that could be viewed on lower timeframes.**

You can create for example a indicator and put that on `D` or `4h` (240) in your case.
Just like in the picture your showing. But if you want to mix this with other logic it would not work because everything would be based on that timeframe and that timeframe alone.

I used/abused the [request.security](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request%7Bdot%7Dsecurity) function for this.

Here is a example of a indicator that will show you the close of the 4h. You can check it on the 2h chart, if this is the behaviour you want.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)
plot(request.security(syminfo.ticker, "240", close, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off))
```